# Issues setting variables through appsetting files in .NET 7

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I am not able to see on my Azure App Service Configuration (or accessing by Kudus), variables I set in `appSettings.json` files in the program file.

Example of `appsettings.json` on the .NET 7 project:

```
{
  "MyVariable1": "Hello",
  "MyVariable2": "World!",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Image from Kudus]

I'm not able to see "MyVariable1", "MyVariable2" in AppSettings.

I'm working on a web application on .NET 7.0, then in the `program.cs` file I'm reading the `appsettings.json` file like this:

```
// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Attempt #1 - Not working
builder.Configuration    
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)    
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// Attempt #2 - Not working
string? baseDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(baseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings{environment}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// Attempt #3 - Not working
string? baseDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(baseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings{environment}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// Attempt #4 - Not working
string? baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location);
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(baseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile(path: Path.Combine(baseDirectory, $"appsettings{environment}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

BTW, I have already set "Copy Always" option for every single `appsettings` file. Anyways, it does not work.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.Staging.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Does anybody knows what I'm missing about this?

Comment: The Configurations which you have set in `appsettings.json` file are not available in the Configuration Section of Azure App Service.Still you can use them.They are compiled into dll files and are available for using.

Comment: The values which are set in Configuration section of App Service are only available in KUDU Console. Will post an answer in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same configurations in`appsettings.json` file which you have provided and deployed the App to Azure App Service.

You can see the values are neither available in the `Configuration Section` nor in the `KUDU Console` - `App Settings`.

***Configuration:***
[image]

***KUDU Console***
[image]

- You can see the `appsettings.json` is also deployed.
  ***Path :***
  `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Navigate to the KUDU Console, select `CMD` from   `Debug Console` => `site` => `wwwroot`

[image]

When I tried to retrieve the values from `appsettings.json`, you can see the values are displayed without any issue.

[image]

***.cshtml***

```cs
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration myconfig
<div class="text-center">
<h2>@myconfig["MyVariable1"]</h2>  <h2> @myconfig["MyVariable2"]</h2> 
</div>
```

- When you want to change the values of the Variables (`MyVariable1` and
  `MyVariable2`) which you have set in `appsettings.json` file, then you need to add the key-values in the `Configuration Section` of an `Azure App Service`.
- The key name must be same as mentioned in the `appsettings.json` file.

***Application Settings:***

[image]

- The above values are now available in KUDU App Settings.

[image]

***Updated values from App Service:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Harshitta. Could you tell me which of the four (4) attempts I posted in my original question did you use for your answer? Please.

Comment: I have used the 1st Attempt It worked for me .So I haven't tried the next 3.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal.

Much like you have added 3 sources of configuration in your attempt one, many sources can be added and `appsettings.json` is just one of them.

The values you configure directly in the App Service Configuration are another. The online editor (and Kudu as you are using it) is only concerned with these and hence only showing them, but all sources added are available to your running code.

Note that `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` is already doing what you are trying to do with the various attempts in your question, [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-application-configuration-sources), so that code is not needed in most scenarios.

See [the docs on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) for more details.